# How to select data from 2 tables by id

Tags: sql, xml, export

I have a script to get data from a table and export to xml, but i need to get the data from 2 different tables.

```
Table 1: Products

i have inside:

id code

Table 2: Stock

i have inside

id qty
```

my script is:

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";

    $db_name = "test";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";

    $dbh = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $dbh) or die("Could not select $db_name");

    $sql = "select * from products ";

    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $custom = '"';

    $xml = "\n";
    $xml .= "<XML>\n";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {

        $xml .= "   <PRODUCT code=$custom " . $r["code"] . "$cusmot qty=$custom " . $r["qty"] . "$custom />\n";

    }
    $xml .= "</XML>";

    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo $xml;
?>
```

Need help to get the qty from Stock result according the id on Products table.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your SQL to pull data from both tables: `select p.code, s.qty from products p, stock s where p.id = s.id`. With that change it looks like your PHP will almost (or completely) work!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you tell me how my suggested query did not work? Did you get your script working?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, s.qty
FROM products p
INNER JOIN stock s ON p.id = s.id
```

Comment: No problem. What do you mean by 'not work'? The SQL is correct based on the information you've provided. If you've solved it yourself, you should post the answer and accept it..

Comment: Hello, no, im not solve this, maybe is correct, but i get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 0):

You should use this query instead of the one present in your code :

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, s.qty
FROM product p, stock s
WHERE p.id = s.id
```

Comment: The result is: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in